# Render XPS glyphs to bitmap using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xps

I want to extract `Glyphs` from `XPS` document and render them at their positions and format to a bitmap. so I can load the `XPS` document and iterate its pages then  iterate all elements, now I can get `Glyphs` elements and read their attributes.
I am not familiar with WPF but I read that I can Use `Glyphs`, `GlyphsRun` and `GlyphsRunDrawing` to draw the Glyphs, I am confused between the Glyphs and GlyphsRun classes both have similar properties, also I am confused about the `Indices` I don't know how to load the from attribute  to the property which is a list of integers.

```
<Glyphs
FontUri="../Resources/Fonts/latha.ttf"
UnicodeString="&#xbaa;&#xbcb;&#xba4;&#xbc1;"
Indices="(2:3)94;76;88;(2:1)162"
OriginX="10" OriginY="120"
FontRenderingEmSize="40"
Fill="#000000"/>
```

I want to create drawing objects here then draw them to bitmaps:

```
Glyphs glyphs = new Glyphs();
GlyphRun glyphRun = new GlyphRun();
glyphs.UnicodeString = pageContentReader.GetAttribute("UnicodeString");
glyphs.BidiLevel= Int32.Parse(pageContentReader.GetAttribute("BidiLevel"));
glyphRun.Characters = pageContentReader.GetAttribute("UnicodeString").ToList();
glyphRun.AdvanceWidths = pageContentReader.GetAttribute("AdvanceWidth").Split(';').Select(o => Double.Parse(o)).ToList();
glyphRun.BaselineOrigin = new System.Windows.Point(Int32.Parse(pageContentReader.GetAttribute("OriginX"))
                            , Int32.Parse(pageContentReader.GetAttribute("OriginY")));
glyphRun.FontRenderingEmSize = Double.Parse(pageContentReader.GetAttribute("FontRenderingEmSize"));
glyphRun.BidiLevel = Int32.Parse(pageContentReader.GetAttribute("BidiLevel"));
```

Comment: Have you read [Introduction to the GlyphRun Object and Glyphs Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/introduction-to-the-glyphrun-object-and-glyphs-element)?

Comment: When you have created a GlyphRun, you would draw it into a DrawingVisual by [​Draw​Glyph​Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawglyphrun?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_DrawingContext_DrawGlyphRun_System_Windows_Media_Brush_System_Windows_Media_GlyphRun_), then render the DrawingVisual into a RenderTargetBitmap.

Comment: @Clemens yes I did, I am working on windows forms and load XPS document

Comment: @MohamedMoussa: Hi have you ever figured this out? I need the glyph position as well